# Why does my iOS app compress so well?

Tags: ios, xcode, packaging

I'm baffled by how Xcode is managing to compress my iOS app so effectively. All of my images and sound files combined add up to 282 MB for about 3000 items. However, the .app is somehow only 126 MB! Further, the file sizes inside the .app package contents are the same, yet the folder sizes are all roughly half size. How is this possible?

Comment: It's not Xcode, it's the ZIP algorithm.

Comment: And btw this is as off topic as possible.

Comment: I thought the .ipa was zipped, but the .app was just an ordinary app bundle like on Mac OS.

Comment: seems like you would benefit from compressing your images.

Comment: This was after running ImageOptim on over 2000 images, which saved about 13 MB. In terms of lossy compression, there are way too many images in the project for my to go through them individually.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason is probably that all your images (assuming images make up the majority of the 282 MBs in your app) are compressed using [pngcrush](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pngcrush) as a build step in your application. You can actually watch this by looking at at the build log from xcode.

The special version of pngcrush that is used in the iOS SDK cause the PNG images to be non-standard (making them unviewable on the Mac or any other standard program for that matter). Instead, they are adapted to the display hardware of the iOS devices which means that they will load faster as well.

Comment: This isn't the reason why my app gets smaller though. I have a folder full of music files which gets smaller as well. Further, I've already run ImageOptim on all the images in the project. Images are actually only about half of the app size.

Comment: To clarify, the Finder shows the music at the same size, but getting info on the containing folder shows a reduced size.

Comment: What does `du -h` on that folder give you?

Comment: `du` displays disk usage statistics. The `-h` flag makes `du`'s output human readable.

Comment: @qegal I meant to suggest this command to be used to compare the directories :)